# Django cache invalidation using versioning

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a template fragment caching like:

```
{% cache 3600 my_list request.path %}
... some html
{% endcache %}
```

the request.path could be in the following form:

- list/2012-01-01
- list/2012-02-01
- ...

I've searched so far and read that to invalidate everything under the name 'my_list' I could use versioning and just increment the version using `cache.incr_version`, but it accepts a key which I don't know since there's no way to predict what URL the user is accessing.

Basically those urls just list some models and when a new one is added, I want to invalidate the cache so it reflects the newly added record. But I can't call `.delete` or `.incr_version` because I don't know the full key.